Asymptotic Time Complexity for Matrix Multipication by Divide and Conqure
I recently learnt how Strassen's algorithm for matrix multiplication reduces asymptotic time complexity from usual O(n^3) to O(n^log2(7)) by doing 7 smaller multiplications instead of 8, is there a way to see from before hand the minimum number of smaller multipications needed to compute the matrix. Also if is instead of dividing matrix into 2*2 smaller matrices if were to divide it into k*k smaller matrices for any k, what would be the best asymptotic time complexity for matrix multiplication we could achieve.
I am not able to get the minimum number of smaller multiplications needed after dividing matrix into k*k smaller matrices.
